# No caption property for Facebook Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta, caption

So basically, because I am on mobile, I can't use the www.facebook.com/sharer.php. I have to use Open Graph meta tags on my page and share that page using the m.facebook.com/sharer.php. The issue I am currently having is that it's impossible to specify the caption of the share through open graph meta tags. It keeps using the domain of the URL. With the web sharer you can specify the caption and it will place it under the title.

Does anyone know how I can specify the caption of a share in Open graph using meta tags? There doesn't seem to be a meta tag that equates to the caption query string parameter of the web sharer.

Answer (score 0):

The `sharer.php` endpoints have been officially deprecated for a while now. You should not be developing new code that relies on these as they could stop working at any time.

You should use the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) instead. It gives you the ability to set a custom caption.

Comment: "The sharer.php endpoints have been officially deprecated for a while now." Reference? I've been unable to find any official deprecation statement from Facebook on this.

Comment: [The Share Dialog's documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share/), for example, mentions nothing about deprecation.

Comment: Facebook is maddening because the documentation does not stay consistent over time. There are no change logs, and because all their documentation is password protected, archive.org isn't any help either. It appears as though the `sharer.php` endpoint may be back. For now.

Comment: I would leave the answer as is.  For a little while Facebook even had a documentation page back up on how to use sharer.php, and it is no longer available, just the brief mention in the Share Dialog documentation now.  Personally, the Feed Dialog is almost always the way to go.  The sharer.php dialog is often buggy and doesn't always respect the other standards Facebook has put into place regarding Open Graph, etc.

Comment: The Feed Dialog for web has been deprecated in API Version 2.0.